# Adding rows to the final page of a pagedlist

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<div>
    <table ​>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var a in Model.Attachments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @a.CId
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ViewAttachment", new { Id = a.CId })">@a.CName</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @a.CType
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Attachments, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</div>
```

Currently I am displaying 25 items per page. If the final page does not have 25 items, I want to append rows to the end of the table, to keep the Page selector at the same level from page to page.
This seems like it would work, I just don't know where to put it:

```
@for (int i = 25; i > Model.Attachments.Count() % 25; i--)
{
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have for sure a loop thrown the attachments list.
Put this loop right after the loop where you write your TRs.

Just take into account that if your data makes your TRs higher, this will break your solution. Other thing you may try is adding a HTML space in your dummy rows: `&nbsp;`

```
<div>
    <table ​>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var a in Model.Attachments)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @a.CId
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ViewAttachment", new { Id = a.CId })">@a.CName</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @a.CType
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
       @for (int i = 25; i > Model.Attachments.Count() % 25; i--)
       {
            <tr>
               <td></td>
            </tr>
       }
    </table>
        @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.Attachments, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }))
</div>
```